# How to perform Public Key Encryption with RSA using C++

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to implement asymmetrc encryption into a project. My end goal is to implement  EVP Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption of an Envelope but for now I am going to stick with the basics.  I am rather new to openssl so please forgive me if there is an obvious answer to this question.

Currently I am following this tutorial here: [Simple Public Key Encryption with RSA and OpenSSL](https://shanetully.com/2012/04/simple-public-key-encryption-with-rsa-and-openssl/)

I plan to transmit the RSA public key over a network to a seperate client which will encrypt a message with the generated public key. The encrypted message will then be sent back to the server for decryption.

I am having trouble with encrypting only using the public key instead of using the keypair. For obvious reasons, I don't want to transmit the keypair over the network.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEY_LENGTH  2048
#define PUB_EXP     3
#define PRINT_KEYS
#define WRITE_TO_FILE

int main(void) {
    size_t pri_len;            // Length of private key
    size_t pub_len;            // Length of public key
    char   *pri_key;           // Private key
    char   *pub_key;           // Public key
    char   msg[KEY_LENGTH/8];  // Message to encrypt
    char   *encrypt = NULL;    // Encrypted message
    char   *decrypt = NULL;    // Decrypted message
    char   *err;               // Buffer for any error messages

    // Generate key pair
    printf("Generating RSA (%d bits) keypair...", KEY_LENGTH);
    fflush(stdout);
    RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, NULL, NULL);

    // To get the C-string PEM form:
    BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri, keypair, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, keypair);

    //SEND KEY TO CLIENT HERE

    //FAKE CLIENT RECIEVE
    RSA *keypair2 = NULL; 
    PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey( pub, &keypair2, NULL, NULL);

    // Get the message to encrypt
    printf("Message to encrypt: ");
    fgets(msg, KEY_LENGTH-1, stdin);
    msg[strlen(msg)-1] = '\0';

    // Encrypt the message using public key only
    encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair2));
    int encrypt_len;
    err = malloc(130);
    if((encrypt_len = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(msg)+1, (unsigned char*)msg, (unsigned char*)encrypt,
                                         keypair2, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1) {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);
        goto free_stuff;
    }

    #ifdef WRITE_TO_FILE
    // Write the encrypted message to a file
        FILE *out = fopen("out.bin", "w");
        fwrite(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt),  RSA_size(keypair), out);
        fclose(out);
        printf("Encrypted message written to file.\n");
        free(encrypt);
        encrypt = NULL;

        // Read it back
        printf("Reading back encrypted message and attempting decryption...\n");
        encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair));
        out = fopen("out.bin", "r");
        fread(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt), RSA_size(keypair), out);
        fclose(out);
    #endif

    //SEND MESSAGE BACK TO CLIENT FOR DECRYPT

    // Decrypt it
    decrypt = malloc(encrypt_len);
    if(RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len, (unsigned char*)encrypt, (unsigned char*)decrypt,
                           keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting message: %s\n", err);
        goto free_stuff;
    }
    printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", decrypt);



    free_stuff:
    RSA_free(keypair);
    BIO_free_all(pub);
    BIO_free_all(pri);
    free(pri_key);
    free(pub_key);
    free(encrypt);
    free(decrypt);
    free(err);

    return 0;
}
```

How could I achieve encrypting data only using the public key rather than the whole keypair?

Thanks

Comment: *`RSA_public_encrypt` ...* - Negative. Rip the code from [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) or [EVP Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption of an Envelope](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Asymmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption_of_an_Envelope). Be sure to use OAEP padding; and not PKCS padding. The OpenSSL team recommends the EVP interfaces for everything.

Comment: You might also be interested in [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww Thanks! I am reading about EVP now. One issue that I am having is passing the public key to my encrypt function. Currently I am transferring the key over the network as a string. Once recieved I want to be able to use the public key, which would be in form of a string,  as the key used for my encrypt functions. How can I achieve this? Thanks